# Different ways to call an imported function from a separate py file, returns error

Tags: python

Not sure if this is a normal python behaviour or a Blender thing

I have a file named `operators.py` and a file named `functions.py`.
also a `__innit__.py` that calls the operators.

**Method 1 :**

in `functions.py`:

```
def someFunction(self, context):
    print("I did it!")
```

in `operators.py`:

```
from functions import someFunction
```

and then later I call the function with:

```
someFunction(self, context)
```

The above resulted in:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'someFunction'
```

**Method 2 :**

in `functions.py`:

```
def someFunction(self, context):
    print("I did it!")
```

in `operators.py`:

```
import functions
```

and then later I call the function with:

```
functions.someFunction(self, context)
```

The above resulted in:

```
AttributeError: module 'functions' has no attribute 'someFunction'
```

So blender did get and import the module but it can't get the functions working.

Comment: How are you running the script? are you opening the files in blender's text editor and running them? or telling blender to run the script from the cli? is the script in the current dir when you start blender?

Comment: opening the files in blender's text editor and running them. Everytime I hv to press `run script` to on each file to get it up and running. Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function seems to be in a class (guessed from the `self` parameter).

Method using `self` are meant to be used on instances.

You should either instanciate the class it belongs to in order to have an instance on which to call the method, or make the function static, or make the function a module function (out of a class definition).

Also the package init file should be named `__init__.py`, not `__innit__.py`.

Comment: thanks i think that's the reason. But i though if i call the function from some other classes, as long i called it with (self, context) parameter it will run the same. for example i have to call a `self.report()` inside the function, how do I achieve that without having the  (self) parameter?

Comment: I have changed the file name to `__init__.py`. On another matter, when I have multiple .py files in the blender text editor, I must press`run script` on every single one of them in order to get everything up and running, is this normal or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I am trying to call the `def` from another class that also have the (self, context) parameter, the `def` itself is not written inside a class. is it not ok?